# Error in parsing value for ‘clip-path’

Tags: javascript, css, clip-path

I'm trying to create clip path around user's mouse. This is my code:

```
const rect = this.image.getBoundingClientRect();
const width = rect.right - rect.left;
const height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

const clipSizePx = 10;
const clipSizePerc = 100 * (clipSizePx / Math.max(width, height));

const mouseXPerc = 100 * ((e.clientX - rect.left) / width);
const mouseXStartPerc = Math_cap(mouseXPerc - clipSizePerc / 2, 0, 100);
const mouseXEndPerc = Math_cap(clipSizePerc/2 + mouseXPerc, 0,100);

const mouseYPerc = 100 * ((e.clientY - rect.top) / height);
const mouseYStartPerc = Math_cap(mouseYPerc - clipSizePerc / 2, 0, 100);
const mouseYEndPerc = Math_cap(mouseYPerc + clipSizePerc / 2, 0, 100);
const clipPath = "clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, "
    + mouseXStartPerc + "% 100%,"
    + mouseXStartPerc + "% " + mouseYStartPerc + "%,"
    + mouseXEndPerc + "% " + mouseYStartPerc + "%,"
    + mouseXEndPerc + "% " + mouseYEndPerc + "%,"
    + mouseXStartPerc + "% " + mouseYEndPerc + "%,"
    + mouseXStartPerc + "% 100%,"
    + " 100% 100%,"
    + " 100% 0%);";
console.log("Clip path: ", clipPath,"\nMouse: ", [mouseXPerc, mouseYPerc]);
this.image.style.clipPath = clipPath;
```

This is the clip path I am trying to assign:

```
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 30.90039334549982% 100%,30.90039334549982% 58.02269121483121%,32.229061634508525% 58.02269121483121%,32.229061634508525% 59.351359503839916%,30.90039334549982% 59.351359503839916%,30.90039334549982% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
```

This is the error, totally unhelpful:

> Error in parsing value for ‘clip-path’.  Declaration dropped.

I really wonder why have CSS errors been always so unhelpful.

Anyway, does anyone see what's wrong with the clip path?

Comment: It seems to be working fine. Are you only getting an error or are you also not seeing the mask applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule should not be ended with semicolon

```
el.style.clipPath = "polygon(...)";   // OK
el.style.clipPath = "polygon(...);";  // Fail
```